# SilverStripe "Translatable" Multilingual content

Tags: php, silverstripe

The Translatable module seems to split the content in different languages (in my case, 3 extra languages) as it's supposed to.

However, there is one specific content part (a gridfield that allows car seller to add "Dealers" to the page) I want to be identical in each language / locale.

Unfortunately the previously entered records (65 records) are only allocated to 1 the default language.

**How can I make Translatable exclude a certain dataobject from splitting to different languages?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Untranslatable Field module](https://github.com/Taitava/silverstripe-untranslatablefields) was created to solve this problem.

And there is no official solution to [this issue](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable/issues/3)